# HTTP Error: 400, Billing account for project '38543xxxxxxx' firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When i try to deploy my cloud functions (firebase)

I get this error:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Billing account for project '385437835946' is not found. Billing must be enabled for activation of service(s) 'cloudbuild.googleapis.com,containerregistry.googleapis.com' to proceed.
```

I need help please

Answer (score 10):

You must be on the Blaze plan with a valid billing account to deploy Cloud Functions on Node.js 10 or later. See [this FAQ answer](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#expandable-10) for more details.

Comment: When did it become necessary to be on the blaze plan before being able to deploy Cloud Functions?

Comment: In August 2020. If you were already using Cloud Functions, you should have received an email about the upcoming change back in May/June.

Comment: my Node.js is 8.17.0 and i still have this problem

Comment: It doesn't depend on your local Node.js version, but on the version specified in the package.json in your `functions` directory. Also, Node.js 8 is deprecated and will stop working in early 2021, so I wouldn't recommend building new things with it.

Comment: Yes; I tried, just switch to node 8 in package.json located in functions/package.json and it worked.   "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },